# How does the MDF file work?

Tags: sql-server, mdf

Let's say I have database with a `.MDF` file of 100 GB and which is 80% full (80 GB used out of 100 GB available).

Within this database I have a table which contributes 40 GB to the `.MDF` file.

My questions are:

1. If I delete 20 GB worth or records will my `.MDF` file stay the same in terms of size (100 GB)? Also, will it reflect to the free space on/inside the `.mdf` file, meaning it will indicate that the `.mdf` file is now 60% full?
2. Over time, if I add back records to my table leading up to another 20 GB of data (on the same table), will my `.MDF` file stay the same at 100 GB? And will it reflect that I will be back at 80% capacity for my `.mdf` file (meaning I now am back to 20 gb free space on my `.mdf` file)?

Thanks

Comment: You need to get and read [the SQL Server 2012 Internals book](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2013/12/06/new-book-microsoft-sql-server-2012-internals.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using 2005 though atm

Comment: There's also a 2005 edition of that book (which you'll find on Amazon or Barnes&Noble or wherever you buy your books) - and the basics of those mechanics don't change all that much

Comment: basically, le mdf acts as a device. It will not shrink unless tyou specifically order it, and it will grow automatically if your allowed it in the file options. So : 1/ the size will stay the same, 2/ yes, it will not need to grow.

Comment: @rudibruchez use that comment as an answer and I'll tag it as the correct one lol